# Using @PUT with Retrofit 2 and OkHttp3

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Currently, I am using Android with Retrofit 2.0.0-beta4 and OkHttp3.  I am doing a @PUT request defined as so:

```
@Headers({
        Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER + ": " + Constants.JSON_HEADER_VAL,
        Constants.ACCEPT_HEADER + ": " + Constants.JSON_HEADER_VAL
})
@PUT(Constants.PUT_SKILL_LEVEL)
Call<EmployeeSkill> updateEmpSkillLevel(@Header(Constants.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME) String cookieValue, @Body EmployeeSkillRequest employeeSkillUpdate);
```

The endpoint goes here: http://apps:8080/employeeSkillsService/employeeSkill.  Here is the log output from the PUT request:

```
D/OkHttp﹕ --> PUT http://apps:8080/employeeSkillsService/employeeSkill http/1.1
D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Length: 99
D/OkHttp﹕ Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp﹕ JSESSIONID: D147377AB60AFE499D2A1AAF7C93F7A3
D/OkHttp﹕ {"employee":{"id":63},"skill":{"isPrimary":false,"isSecondary":false,"id":3},"skillLevel":{"id":5}}
D/OkHttp﹕ --> END PUT (99-byte body)
<-- 404 Not Found http://apps:8080/employeeSkillsService/app.html (23ms)
D/OkHttp﹕ Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
D/OkHttp﹕ X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`D/OkHttp﹕ X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`
D/OkHttp﹕ X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
D/OkHttp﹕ Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp﹕ Pragma: no-cache
D/OkHttp﹕ Expires: 0
D/OkHttp﹕ X-Frame-Options: DENY
D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Language: en
D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Length: 1029
D/OkHttp﹕ Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 15:39:35 GMT
D/OkHttp﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1457365206407
D/OkHttp﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1457365206412
D/OkHttp﹕ <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu) - Error report</title><style><!--H1 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /employeeSkillsService/app.html</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/employeeSkillsService/app.html</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)</h3></body></html>
D/OkHttp﹕ <-- END HTTP (1029-byte body)
```

I have verified in Postman on Chrome that this endpoint with these headers and payload works multiple times.  Yet when I use Retrofit I keep receiving a 404 error despite the endpoint working in Postman.  Here is the code call:

```
Call<EmployeeSkill> updateEmployeeSkillCall = RetrofitApiRestClient.getApiClient().updateEmpSkillLevel(cookieValue, employeeSkillUpdate);

updateEmployeeSkillCall.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeSkill>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<EmployeeSkill> call, Response<EmployeeSkill> response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            holder.spnSkillLevel.setTag(pos);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, holder.tvSkillName.getText() + mContext.getString(R.string.skill_updated_success_text)
                + holder.spnSkillLevel.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            List<EmployeeSkill> updateEmployeeSkillsRow = EmployeeSkill.find(EmployeeSkill.class, "employee = ? and skill = ?",
                response.body().getEmployee().getId().toString(), response.body().getSkill().getId().toString());

            EmployeeSkill updatedSkill = updateEmployeeSkillsRow.get(0);
            updatedSkill.setSkillLevel(response.body().getSkillLevel());
            updatedSkill.setTimeUpdated(response.body().getSkillLevel().getTimeUpdated());
            updatedSkill.save();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<EmployeeSkill> call, Throwable throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, holder.tvSkillName.getText() + mContext.getString(R.string.skill_update_failed_text), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

I have tried changing the @Body parameter to a JSON String, but I received an error that stated that the JSON must begin with an array or object.  Any help in this matter would be useful.  Without this functionality, I will be forced to scrap Retrofit if I cannot find a solution and I am not really looking forward to doing that.

Comment: Are you sure that the method is PUT instead of POST? Can you post the request made using retrofit? You would get a 404 if the web service is expecting the method to be something other than PUT (i.e., POST, GET), even if the url and headers are all correct.

Comment: I can verify that PUT does work when using Postman with that exact JSON payload.  But that is the confusing part.  "404" should not be occurring.  Here is the response using Retrofit: `D/OkHttp﹕ <-- 404 Not Found http://apps:8080/employeeSkillsService/app.html (27ms)`

Comment: Tried using RequestBody as well and got the same response

Comment: Can you post the request instead of the response?

Comment: The Retrofit request log is above.  Anything specific you're looking for?

Comment: What are the values of `Constants.PUT_SKILL_LEVEL` and your `baseUrl`?

Comment: The baseUrl  is http://apps:8080/employeeSkillsService/.   Constants.PUT_SKILL_LEVEL is **employeeSkill**.

Comment: the 404 you mention in the comment is not from that PUT request. It is a different url. post the complete log of the request (and response, obviously) in one place, instead of adding information in the comments

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect both the request and the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue using Fiddler2. Had the cookie name and value incorrect. Postman was probably more forgiving in how it sent things vs. how Retrofit and others did so.  Learned something from it, though. Thanks to all who assisted.